# Mvc.Net show many results from web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging

I have an mvc 4.0 system that uses other system's web api service. The problem is that sometimes the service returns ~11,000 records, and the web page gets stuck and unable to show all of them.
How can I solve this problem? If the data was stored in my database, I would try to implement paging, but that's not the case.

Comment: You can still implement paging in the controller so that your view only displays a limited number of records

Comment: Is it safe to bring so many  records to the controller (in terms of stability)?

Comment: Performance wont be great but at least you will only be generating the html for x records.  But its a poor api that returns that many records and does not allow you to page them.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, the best practice will be that the system that expose the web api, will also allow paging?

Comment: Well it should if it can return that many records)